# How to modify side nav bar in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I am using SharePoint 2013, In this I want to modify I want to modify sidebar navigation and wants to show the menu level upto four level.I am tying to modify the seattle.master to show the menu by adding the code from the oslo.master file. Can you please advise how I can achieve this task in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Change StaticDisplyLevels and MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels, the StaticDisplayLevels defines the number of the major levels, and the MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels defines the number of the deeper menu levels.

Open your site with SharePoint Designer->edit master page->find V4QuickLaunchMenu->Change StaticDisplyLevels and MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels.

Reference:

https://www.advisicon.com/blog/right-way-enable-quicklaunch-fly-menu-sharepoint-2013/

https://olafd.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/sharepoint-2013-fly-out-menu-in-quick-launch/

Comment: Thanks, worked for me.

Comment: Please remember to mark the helpful post as an answer. Thanks for your understanding.